# Cause for disagreement in queue depth between runmqsc and MQ Explorer

Tags: ibm-mq

We have a monitoring tool using `runmqsc` with the command:

```
display qstatus(*) curdepth ipprocs
```

to retrieve queue depths for alarming purposes <sup>(a)</sup>.

A script analyses the output and feeds the information to a database, so I'm just waiting on the *raw* output of that command above to ensure it's not something wrong with the script. That's unlikely since all the other queues report fine.

So the problem is that it reports a depth of 139 for a particular queue, and it's been at that value for many hours. MQ Explorer on that box however, seems to think there's only eight messages in the queue.

Hence my question is (hopefully) a simple one: under what circumstances would `display qstatus curdepth` disagree with MQ Explorer in terms of the queue depth? Is there some *other* metric I should be gathering from `runmqsc` to get the correct depth? Or is MQ Explorer not necessarily as reliable? <sup>(b)</sup>

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The purpose of producing alarms, not purposes you should be alarmed about.

<sup>(b)</sup> Yes, I *know* that's three questions. I prefer to think of it as three aspects of the *same* question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both runmqsc and MQ Explorer (via PCF) display the same value that the queue manager gives to them. If both commands were issued at **exactly** the same time they would give the sme answer. Of course, CURDEPTH is something that can change rapidly, so please be sure that it isn't simply an actual change in the depth between issuing the command with one tool and the other tool.

Comment: The depth had been eight for several weeks, a consequence of us only doing correlated GETs meaning that messages that we timed out waiting for (and that still came in later) were left in the queue. Then, eight hours before I posted the question, it jumped to 140-odd for the exact same reason. While the queue depth went up and down due to messages coming in and being retrieved, those 140-odd never budged (think `8 9 8 9 8 9 10 9 8 140 141 140 141 140 ...`). So I'm pretty certain it's not a timing issue between Explorer and runmqsc.

Comment: Having said that, I've just received notification from the support bods that, when they shut down Explorer and restarted it a couple of times, it eventually came good and started reported the higher figure. So this is probably the "best" answer in that it raises the possibility of delays. Why it took days and why it had to be restarted more than once, I have no idea, but it's fixed now. From now on, I'm trusting runmqsc only :-)

Answer (score 1):

MQExplorer has a default refresh interval of 15 seconds, meaning the MQExplorer contents are refreshed with queue manager statistics every 15 secondss. On the other hand runmqsc commands display the statics at the time the command is executed. Hence the 'disagree' could be due to the MQExplorer view not being refreshed.

Comment: Good point, I should have mentioned the queue jumped up to 139 in the early hours of the morning, some eight hours ago. I'll clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the wrong command.  QStatus is reporting the high value and will continue to report until a ResetQ command is done against the queue then it again will report the high value.

You should be using the following MQSC command:

```
display qlocal(*) curdepth ipprocs
```

Comment: The doco for `display qstatus` describes `curdepth` as "the **current** depth of the queue, that is, the number of messages on the queue" (my bold). What leads you to suggest it's holding a high water mark? As a test, I threw 7000-odd transactions into a queue and both `qstatus` and `qlocal` had `curdepth` of that amount. When I emptied the queue, both reported zero.

Comment: Roger, I think you're mixing up Qstats with Qstatus